# Why I get the error "OleDbConnection" is not defined?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I have been trying to create a simple login page using Windows Form(vb.net)
I connected my MS Access database to my windows form and when I try to write the code, it shows error. Basically the problem is that, When I try to write:

```
Dim co as New OleDbConnection()
```

it says that `OleDb` is not defined. I tried this in my College computer and it worked perfectly. In the suggestions also it doesn't show `OleDbConnection`. Yes, I have used `Imports.System.OleDb` and yet it doesn't work. Any solutions? Thanks!

Here is the Code,

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection()
    End Sub
End Class
```

while writing `OleDbConnection` it doesn't appear in the suggestion as well.
Also, I tried this with `SqlClient` and had the same problem.

Comment: You have probably created a project targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework. In that case, you need to add the appropriate NuGet package for each ADO.NET provider.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I reviewed that and here is the updated one and yet it doesn't solve the error. Thanks for notifying me and lemme know if there's anything I can do to fix this error. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hey @John thanks for the answer and yes I have created this project targeting .Net core. I am sorry I don't quite understand what you said about adding NuGet Package for ADO.Net. Am new to this thing. Can you please elaborate? Do you mean I need to install some kind of Extension? Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to work with .NET Core then you will need to understand NuGet, so you should spend some time researching that. For now, right-click the project and select the NuGet option, then install the System.Data.OleDb package. I'm not sure whether I get this functionality from ReSharper but you may be able to click the type name in code, click the icon that appears in the left margin and select the option to find the type on NuGet. If available, that will find the appropriate package for you.

Comment: Hey @John. It worked! I installed System.Data.OleDb package as you said. Thanks alot man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET Framework, the `SqlClient` and `OleDb` providers are included in the *System.Data.dll* assembly, which is referenced by default in a WinForms project. In .NET Core, each provider is in its own assembly and you need to add them as required by installing the appropriate NuGet package.

There are a number of ways to use NuGet but I tend to use the GUI built into VS. You can right-click a project in the *Solution Explorer* and select *Manage NuGet Packages* to open it. You can then search for the appropriate NuGet package - *System.Data.OleDb* in this case - and install the latest version or a specific version if desired. That will add the appropriate assembly reference to your project, thus giving you access to types declared in that assembly.

Comment: Actually we weren't taught about NuGet and it's packages at the college and so had no idea about it. thanks alot for the answer and have a good day ;)

Comment: Hey @John, I understood that and it worked for me but do I have to install it every time I create a project? or is there a way to install it once and then it is available for all the projects? Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Dilip, NuGet packages are project-specific, so you have to install it every time. The idea is that your app is as lean as possible, so only those types that most people are likely to use are available by default. Anything else, you have to add explicitly. Given how quick and easy it is to add a package, I don't think it will be a problem. If you remember/save the console command, you can do it in a matter of seconds in the Package Manager Console window. That said, you may be able to create your own project template that includes specific packages. never tried so not sure.

Comment: @Yeh, I Just downloaded the package and added it, will try to create a project template now. Thanks a lot for the help man. Greatly appreciated. ;)

Comment: @Dilip, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue. That helps everyone because they can see that you need no more help without opening the question.